# MongoDB Atlas Error for java mongo java driver 3.4.0 and above

Tags: java, mongodb

I am getting the below error., when i use mongo atlas with mongo java driver 3.4.0. if i use the mongo java driver less than 3.4.0 version am getting different error. kindly suggest some thing

INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-02-me1wd.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveReply(CommandHelper.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:121)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:45)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dec 06, 2017 9:04:19 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-00-me1wd.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveReply(CommandHelper.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:121)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:45)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dec 06, 2017 9:04:19 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-01-me1wd.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveReply(CommandHelper.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:121)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:45)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Could you share snippet of your Java code that makes the connection ? Do you get the error all the time or intermittently ? Are you using other Java frameworks. i.e. Spring etc. Are you using MongoDB Atlas M0 Free Tier ? Please see also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

That was my mistake.... IP address which I had added to the securities in Atlas had changed. I have updated it with new IP & it's working fine.